# How to get mod_rewrite specific log messages in Windows Server and which file do I need to get?

Tags: apache-2.4, powershell, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf, 301-redirect

I have an issue on getting mod_rewrite specific log. I found [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) on a website and with help from a friend I managed to get this to run in Windows Server Powershell. 
Below is the command line:

```
Get-content -Path D:/wamp64/xxx -wait -tail 10 | select-string -pattern "\[rewrite:"
```

And my issue now is which file I need to get the content from to get the redirection logs? httpd.conf? .htaccess? Do I need to change anything else? I am sure that I need to point it to the correct path/file but I'm not sure which file to specified as it does not mention in [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging). I've also tried to create custom logs before but failed and causing the website to be down(which might be because of apache version? my apache is version 2.4.37)

Please help me and TIA! Kindly drop a message here you need anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to get rewrite logs by adding below for apache 2.4.37 in httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog "d:/wamp64/logs/rewrite.log"
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace8
```

Make sure to create a log with rewrite.log in folder logs so all the rewrite logs will go to that file.